# Marking plain -init to have a nullable return type without a warning

Tags: objective-c, compiler-warnings, return-type, objective-c-nullability

I have an ObjC class inheriting from `NSObject` that wraps some third-party library macros so that I can use their functionality in Swift. The class has an ivar that's a container type from the library. Creation of the container can fail, and if it does, the instantiation of my class should fail too. So I marked `-init` as `nullable`.

```
@interface BasketWrapper : NSObject

/**
 * @abstract  Create an empty basket
 */
 - (nullable instancetype)init;    // ⚠️ Conflicting nullability specifier

@end

@implementation
{
    LibraryBasket * _basket;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if( !self ) return nil;

    // Can't really do anything without the wrapped item.
    _basket = LibraryBasket_Create();
    if( !_basket ) return nil;

    return self;
}
```

Unfortunately that `-init` declaration produces a compiler warning

> Conflicting nullability specifier on return types, '_Nullable' conflicts with existing specifier 'nonnull'

pointing at `NSObject`'s declaration.

As a workaround, I've marked the warning ignored with a pragma, and the method appears in Swift as failable.

Another option I considered was to mark plain `-init` unavailable and make a class method, `+empty`, instead. But then that's annoying because a) I can't use Swift initializer syntax, and b) `init` is unavailable in the class's own implementation too.

Is there some way to override the nullability of the inherited `init` without the warning?

Comment: Perhaps you can extend `NSProxy` instead of `NSObject`. I imagine there would be more work to do so, but it may be an option.

Comment: That's an interesting thought, thanks. "Proxy" certainly makes some sense semantically.

Comment: Is this a singleton?

Comment: It is not, @Willeke.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a factory method having the same name as the type:

```
@interface BasketWrapper : NSObject

+ (nullable instancetype)basketWrapper;

/**
 * @abstract  Create an empty basket
 */
- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;

@end
```

This will make the warning go away and allow you to make use of the failable initializer.